# How do I install pyvenn package in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, venn-diagram

I've been trying to do venn diagram with Jupyter Notebook, but I don't know how to install the Pyvenn Package.

I tried using this line
`!pip install pyvenn`

but this error shows

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().system('pip install pyvenn')

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2590, in InteractiveShell.system_piped(self, cmd)
   2585     raise OSError("Background processes not supported.")
   2587 # we explicitly do NOT return the subprocess status code, because
   2588 # a non-None value would trigger :func:`sys.displayhook` calls.
   2589 # Instead, we store the exit_code in user_ns.
-> 2590 self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(self.var_expand(cmd, depth=1))

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py:129, in ProcessHandler.system(self, cmd)
    125 enc = DEFAULT_ENCODING
    127 # Patterns to match on the output, for pexpect.  We read input and
    128 # allow either a short timeout or EOF
--> 129 patterns = [pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.EOF]
    130 # the index of the EOF pattern in the list.
    131 # even though we know it's 1, this call means we don't have to worry if
    132 # we change the above list, and forget to change this value:
    133 EOF_index = patterns.index(pexpect.EOF)

AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [package](https://pypi.org/project/venn/0.1.3/) for [venn digarams](https://github.com/LankyCyril/pyvenn/blob/master/pyvenn-demo.ipynb)

```
!pip install venn

from venn import venn
%matplotlib inline

musicians = {
    "Members of The Beatles": {"Paul McCartney", "John Lennon", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"},
    "Guitarists": {"John Lennon", "George Harrison", "Jimi Hendrix", "Eric Clapton", "Carlos Santana"},
    "Played at Woodstock": {"Jimi Hendrix", "Carlos Santana", "Keith Moon"}
}
venn(musicians)
```